# Bizarre, randomly timed scraping errors

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

so I've got a functioning scrapy web crawler that will search a given url ("amazon.ca" + "sku(from a csv)") and then return some info from this page and then follow a link into a 2nd level page and extract an image... but it stops working after 300 or so URL crawls. This is the traceback for an item that gives me issue:

```
    2019-08-28 10:07:31 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.ca/s?k=9781908724595> (referer: None)
    2019-08-28 10:07:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.ca/Motor-City-Madhouse-Going-Nugent/dp/1908724595/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=9781908724595&qid=1567001251&s=gateway&sr=8-1> (referer: https://www.amazon.ca/s?k=9781908724595)
    2019-08-28 10:07:33 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'artist': 'Martin Popoff',
     'image_urls': [None],
     'sku': '9781908724595',
     'theurl': 'https://www.amazon.ca/Motor-City-Madhouse-Going-Nugent/dp/1908724595/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=9781908724595&qid=1567001251&s=gateway&sr=8-1',
     'title': 'Motor City Madhouse: Going Gonzo with Ted Nugent'}
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
      File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\pipelines\media.py", line 79, in process_item
        requests = arg_to_iter(self.get_media_requests(item, info))
      File "C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\scraper\scrapy2\pipelines.py", line 20, in get_media_requests
        for x in item.get('image_urls', [])]
      File "C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\scraper\scrapy2\pipelines.py", line 20, in <listcomp>
        for x in item.get('image_urls', [])]
      File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 25, in __init__
        self._set_url(url)
      File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 63, in _set_url
        raise TypeError('Request url must be str or unicode, got %s:' % type(url).__name__)
    TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got NoneType:
    2019-08-28 10:07:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

I know I'm doing some pretty random stuff to narrow in on my desired content  before saving as items (below), but everything seems to work and it just stops randomly at certain items and shows the error despite scraping and showing the URLs correctly in the terminal output.

Here's my crawler:

```html
import scrapy
import csv
from scrapy2.items import Scrapy2Item
  
class spider1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider1"
    domain = "https://www.amazon.ca/s?k="

    with open("C:/Users/Tyler/Desktop/scraper/scrapy2/spiders/csv/input.csv", newline="") as csvfile:
        skureader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')

        sku_list = []

        for row in skureader:
            sku_list.append(''.join(row))

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.sku_list:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=spider1.domain+url, callback = self.parse)

    custom_settings = {
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': 1
    }

    def parse(self, response):

        RESULT_SELECTOR = ".sg-col-20-of-24" + \
                          ".s-result-item" + \
                          ".sg-col-0-of-12" + \
                          ".sg-col-28-of-32" + \
                          ".sg-col-16-of-20" + \
                          ".sg-col" + \
                          ".sg-col-32-of-36" + \
                          ".sg-col-12-of-16" + \
                          ".sg-col-24-of-28"


        for dataset in response.css(RESULT_SELECTOR):

            items = Scrapy2Item()

            titlevar = dataset.css('span.a-text-normal ::text').extract_first()
            artistvar = dataset.css('span.a-size-base ::text').extract()

            skuvar = response.xpath('//meta[@name="keywords"]/@content')[0].extract()

            skuvar_split = skuvar.split(',', 1)[0]
            artistvar_split = artistvar[1]

            if any ("Sponsored" in s for s in artistvar):
                items['artist'] = "DELETE THIS"
                items['sku'] = "DELETE THIS"
                items['title'] = "DELETE THIS"
            elif any("by " in s for s in artistvar):
                items['artist'] = artistvar_split
                items['sku'] = skuvar_split
                items['title'] = titlevar
            else:
                items['artist'] = ""
                items['sku'] = skuvar_split
                items['title'] = titlevar

            itempage = response.urljoin(dataset.css('div.a-section > h2.a-size-mini > a ::attr(href)').extract_first())

            items['theurl'] = itempage

            request = scrapy.Request(itempage, callback=self.get_iteminfo)
            request.meta['items'] = items  # By calling .meta, we can pass our item object into the callback.
            yield request  # Return the item info back to the parser.

    def get_iteminfo(self, response):

        items = response.meta['items']  # Get the item we passed from scrape()

        imgvar = [response.css('img#landingImage ::attr(data-old-hires)').extract_first()]
        items['image_urls'] = imgvar

        yield items
```

and then the items.py

```html
import scrapy

class Scrapy2Item(scrapy.Item):
    theurl = scrapy.Field()
    sku = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    artist = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
```

and then the pipelines.py:

```html
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline

import csv

class Scrapy2Pipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        return [scrapy.Request(x, meta={'image_name': item['sku']})
                for x in item.get('image_urls', [])]

    # write in current folder using the name we chose before
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        return '%s.jpg' % request.meta['image_name']


def write_to_csv(item):
   writer = csv.writer(open('C:/Users/Tyler/Desktop/scraper/scrapy2/spiders/csv/output.csv', 'a'), lineterminator='\n')
   writer.writerow([item[sku] for sku in item.keys()])

class WriteToCsv(object):

    def process_item(self, item, info):
        write_to_csv(item)
        return item
```

Comment: could you please add the full traceback?

Comment: error is obvious, you are somehow sending invalid links to Request method, please try to print/debug all links

Answer (score 0):

Aah, I'm a bit of a dummy.

Thanks for taking the time to help me out @AnuvratParashar and @Umair. I believe I was able to figure out the problem. I've added my full traceback above.

The issue was within this section of my scraper, which follows a URL it scrapes and then tries to extract an image URL within this page:

```
    def get_iteminfo(self, response):

            items = response.meta['items']  # Get the item we passed from scrape()

            imgvar = [response.css('img#landingImage ::attr(data-old-hires)').extract_first()]
            items['image_urls'] = imgvar

            yield items
```

It looks like the pages that my crawler stopped extracting info from had different image ids than the rest of my pages and it was basically saying, "hey, these image URLs you're trying to extract don't exist!", and then just not outputting any of the results for these pages (even if there were results from the first scraped page). I was just focusing on the page URLs and getting frustrated because it was showing them without issue in my terminal output... I completely disregarded my image URLs.